# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, osgeo4w, osgeo

I installed QGIS plug-in "AVHYAS is an open source Python 3 tool plugged in QGIS",and installed required libraries however while trying to use some function, I got the following error. The link of the plug-in: https://sites.google.com/view/avhyas-sac-isro/home
I updated matplotlib hover it did not help me.

The error

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/musta/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\HxTools\HxTools.py", line 1927, in doDeepLearning
    from .doDeepLearning import HxToolsDialog
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/musta/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\HxTools\doDeepLearning.py", line 21, in 
    os.path.join(pluginPath, 'HxTools/ui', 'dialogDeepLearning.ui'))
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\PyQt\uic\__init__.py", line 36, in __loadUiType
    return __PyQtLoadUiType(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 201, in loadUiType
    exec(code_string.getvalue(), ui_globals)
  File "", line 477, in 
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/musta/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\HxTools\ui\qmatplotlibwidget2.py", line 42, in 
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg'


Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.14.16-Pi Pi, df27394552 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/musta/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/musta/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\Scripts
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.14\bin\python37.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.14\bin
C:\Users\musta\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/musta/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
```

Comment: I solved this issue by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70473689/10226389

Comment: I followed that way and solved the problem, thanks so much. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70473689/10226389

Answer (score 1):

For me on Windows I just changed:

> from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as
> FigureCanvas

to:

> from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as
> FigureCanvas